# Classifying digits of an integer value

Tags: c++

I spent a day on this code for count even and zero and odd numbers

From long datatype I used a function to send data. Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void digitCount(long long int &num);

int main ()
{
    long long int num;

    cout <<"Enter any No. " <<endl;
    cin >>num;
    cout <<endl;

    digitCount(num);

    return 0;
}


void digitCount(long long  int &num)
{
    int e = 0, z = 0, o = 0, x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
    {
        x= num % 10;    
        if(x == 0)
        {
            ++z;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        else if(x%2==1)
        {
            ++o;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        else
        {
            ++e;
            num = num / 10;
        }  
    }

    cout << "No of zeros Digits = " << z<< endl;
    cout << "No of odd Digits = " << o << endl;
    cout << "No of Even Digits = " << e << endl;
}
```

the problem is when I count odd numbers there is a number missed

for example when i input : 12345

the result is

```
no of even : 2 
no of odd :  2 (should be 3)
no of zero : 0
```

and here the question :

Write a function that takes as parameter an integer (as a long value) and returns the number of odd, even, and zero digits. Also write a program to test your function. Use pass by reference method.

Comment: You should provide a title that describes your question. Something as vague as "Please Any Help ? c++ code" gives no significant information. You should also indent your code properly.

Comment: `num` is `long long int`, but `i` is `int` and you are using `i <= num`. That's not good....

Comment: One day is not a very long time mate.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `for` loop you should use:

```
while (num > 0)
```

You're constantly changing `num` and when it gets to 1 (in your 12345 example), `i` is at 3.  I also modified your `digitcount` to demonstrate some decent formatting for readable code.

```
void digitCount(long long  int &num) {  
    int e(0), z(0), o(0), x(0);

    while (num > 0) {
        x = num % 10;

        if (x == 0) {
            z++;
        }
        else if (x % 2 == 1) {
            o++;
        }
        else {
            e++;
        }

        num /= 10;
    }

    cout << "No of zeros Digits = " << z << endl;
    cout << "No of odd Digits = " << o << endl;
    cout << "No of Even Digits = " << e << endl;
}
```

If you believe this solves your problem && is the best answer, please click the checkmark next to this answer.  Thanks